# What is Koszul dual of a curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, koszul-duality

Let $X$ be a curve embedded into a projective space $\mathbb P$ such that 
it is cut out (scheme-theoretically or ideal-theoretically) by quadrics.

What is known about the Koszul dual of the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$? What is the center of the Koszul dual ring?

Edited: I would be thankful for references regarding even the very basic special cases. For example, $X$ a rational normal curve; or $X$ is an elliptic curve embedded by a full linear system of degree at least $4$. Or, $X$ is any curve, and the divisor is sufficiently large.

Comment: Being cut out by quadrics isn't sufficient to make the homogeneous coordinate ring koszul.

Comment: Of course. There is still a concept of Koszul dual, though.

Comment: Great question! This paper of Bezrukavnikov http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9502021 (apparently never published?) is relevant for $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: See also: Inamdar, Mehta, Frobenius splitting of Schubert varieties and linear syzygies. American Journal of Math.